# Should I use a colon or not?

Tags: colons

I am not certain whether I need to use an additional colon in the following sentence:

> As a result, you get a Managerial Framework: This document answers questions such as Who is in charge? Why does it matter? What does the manager do?

Do I need to add a colon after the words *such as*?

Comment: It would look clumsy (some would say 'be unacceptable') with two colons. Is there a problem with _As a result, you get a 'Managerial Framework'. This document answers questions such as: Who is in charge? Why does it matter? What does the manager do?_? (Perhaps some people object to lists of interrogative sentences after a colon.)

Comment: Thank you Edwin so much for helping me. I agree that having two colons in a sentence looks clumsy. The problem with putting quotations with the words, Managerial Framework, is that the term is a proper noun and not being used as a reference. The reason that I put a colon after Managerial Framework is because the following sentence explains what that term is. So what do you suggest in this case?

Comment: The term is unknown to me and hence I'm quite happy with scare quotes used here to mark an unfamiliar term. This usage is quite accepted, but would not work in a register where the term should already be considered familiar. An alternative (again, only sensible where the term needs explaining) is to use a parenthesis. "As a result, you get a _Managerial Framework_ (a document answering questions such as: Who is in charge? Why does it matter? What does the manager do?)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there should be a colon. However, as Edwin points out, two colons in a single sentence looks clunky and should be avoided. But that problem is easy to fix. Simply divide the sentence into two sentences at the first colon. This is possible because that colon does not introduce a list, just a description. The text after a descriptive colon is often (as in this case) an independent sentence.

> As a result, you get a Managerial Framework. This document answers questions such as: Who is in charge? Why does it matter? What does the manager do?

I don't like the format of that list, so I would write it this way:

> As a result, you get a Managerial Framework. This document addresses matters such as who is in charge, why it matters, and what the manager does.